# :reload-all and existing references

Tags: multithreading, clojure, reload

I just discovered an interesting feature of `:reload-all`. Say I have:

```
(defn clock-update [clock] (swap! clock (fn [previousTime] (+ previousTime 1) )  )   )
(def threads  (Executors/newScheduledThreadPool 16))
(defn start-clock [clock] 
        (. threads scheduleAtFixedRate 
        #(clock-update clock) 0 1 TimeUnit/SECONDS ))
```

and I `(start-clock clock)` where clock is an atom I'm watching, WELL, if I then change the atom swap! function (say, change + for -) in clock-update and `(use :reload-all 'myns)` then guess what, that function is used to update the atom for existing threads instead! I didn't expect that. I thought existing threads would continue to reference whatever function they were constructed with.

Comment: This definitely still works with :reload as well as :reload-all. I tried it.

Comment: I was implicitly asking "why?"

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation explains

> def always applies to the root binding, even if the var is thread-bound at the point where def is called.